# sessionInfo() returns an error after removal of a package

Tags: r, error-handling, package

After removing the *igraph* package using `remove.packages("igraph")`, `sessionInfo()` returns:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  DESCRIPTION file of package 'igraph' is missing or broken
```

It was working fine right before. Any thoughts on why this is happening, and how to get the function to work again?

Comment: This will sound very windowsy, but have you tried restarting the R session?

Comment: You probably need to detach/unload the package. And you might have needed to do that before you removed it.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich So the process would really be the opposite of `install.packages()` + `library()` or `require()`. Let me try to see if this works.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich it worked. I'll accept it if you write an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you deleted the package while your R session still had it attached. That means `sessionInfo` can't find the data it's looking for, which is causing the error.

So, you probably need to run `detach("package:igraph", unload=TRUE)` and then run `remove.packages("igraph")`.

Comment: you might want to add to your answer that the commands are `detach("package:package_name", unload=TRUE)` and then `remove.packages(package_name) `